# Jquery - increment global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment, nicedit

I have the following nicEditor implementation and am trying to change a behavior once I set var over = 1. Here is the desired behavior:

1. Until text length = 5, we get the console message: "under 5, first go"
2. As the text length continues to increase over 5, we get the message: "over 5"
3. If we then reduce the text length back below 5, we get the message: "YAYYYYY, I got it!"

Right now, if the text length goes back below 5, we go back to the "under 5, first go" message. I think the solution is to change the value of var over as a global variable but cannot figure out how to do this. .  Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jGLRn/182

HTML

JS:
     nicEditors.allTextAreas();

```
var over = 0;
$("div.nicEdit-main").keyup(function() {
  var text_count = $(this).text().length;
  if ($(this).text().length < 5) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('#id_desc').val(text);
    console.log("under 5, first go");
  } else {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('#id_desc').val(text);
    console.log("over 5");
    $('.nicEdit-main').removeClass('error');
    $("#id_desc-error").remove();
    over = 1;
  }

  if ((over == 1) && (text < 5)) {
    console.log("YAYYYYY, I got it!");
  }
});
```

Comment: dont reinitialize `var over` inside keyup

Comment: Thanks @guradio. That did not fix the problem. See updated fiddle as per your suggestion: .jsfiddle.net/jGLRn/182

Comment: initialize the value of over to 0 inside the if condition. right now when you change the value to 1 it is always 1. `if ($(this).text().length < 5) {
    over = 0;
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('#id_desc').val(text);
    console.log("under 5, first go");
  }` @ian

Comment: @guradio, thx. That won't work because I only want the console message to read "YAYYYYY, I got it!" if they the text length has first increased upto at least 5. If I do as you suggest, the  "under 5, first go" message will never display.  In other words, I want over to be permanently 1 once the text length goes to 5.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a shadow-variable `over`, since you do `var over` in your `keyup` function, which means inside of keyup, over will always reference the non-global one.  Remove that line and it will work

Comment: Thanks @dave. That did not fix the problem. See updated fiddle as per your suggestions: .jsfiddle.net/jGLRn/182

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jGLRn/183/ - you were checking if `text < 5` but you needed to check if `$(this).text().length < 5`, and I added a check for `over === 0` in your first `if` so that you wouldn't get two `console.log`s

Comment: That got it. Thanks much!

Comment: Actually, it got me 98% there but it pushed me over the edge. In your fiddle, once we go under 5 again, console log still prints "over 5".  Here is my solution that did it all: http://jsfiddle.net/jGLRn/185/ Tx again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `var over;` from `keyup` handler as your handle is using this as a variable and not incrementing the global one.

Comment: Thanks @George Bailey, dave. That did not fix the problem. See updated fiddle as per your suggestions:  .http://jsfiddle.net/jGLRn/182/

Comment: so you only want to display "YAYYYYY, I got it!" when limit is increased and then decreased under 5 ?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/jGLRn/184/ let me know if it does that -:P

Comment: sorry, went to sleep. That got most of the way there. "Less than 5" still showed in console once you reduced text back under 5 again.  Here is my solution that did it all: jsfiddle.net/jGLRn/185